# Angular httpclient.get does returns undefined

Tags: angular7

I have the following code which prints "undefined" to the console

```
    let f:Observable<Asset[]>;
         f= this.http.get<HttpResponse<Asset[]>>(this.baseApiUrl+"Asset",this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(map(
           response=>{
            return response.body;
           }
         ))

         f.subscribe(m=>{console.log(m)});
         return f;
```

However the code I had before worked fine

```
return this.http.get<Asset[]>(this.baseApiUrl+"Asset",this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(map(
       response=>{
        return response;
       }
     ))
```

The headers for both are exactly the same as follows

```
this.httpNormalOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth_token,
          observe:'response'
        })
      }
```

Why does one of these return "undefined" while the other returns a populated array? I have checked on the webservice side and a populated array is being returned in both cases.

Comment: Response is an Asset array. Not a HttpClientResponse

Comment: Yes but in the first example I return the response.body object which is an Asset[] But response.body is undefined...

Comment: You don’t need to use the body attribute.

Comment: Ahhh. So how do I cast it to an Observable<Asset[]>

Answer (score 0):

```
let f:Observable<Asset[]>;
         f= this.http.get<Asset[]>(this.baseApiUrl+"Asset",this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(map(
           response:= Asset[]>{
            return response;
           }
         ))

         f.subscribe(m=>{console.log(m)});
         return f;
```

Comment: I assume you mean, return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Asset[]>>(this.baseApiUrl+"Asset",this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(map(
       response=>{
        return response;
       }
     ))    However it does not work. I get an error saying "Cannot find name response"

Comment: Sorry, the Iphone App is not the best place to edit code

Comment: Lol that is fine. I got what you were saying. However as I said, it does not work as I get an error.